# Error Unknown FileSystem: Grub Rescue?

Tags: boot

I had a dual boot system for Windows 7 and Linux 10.10 . I am new to linux and hadnt upgraded it before ir reached its end-of-life. So I decided to delete the partition in which linux was installed and in the same session downloaded the latest linux version 12.04 using WUBI in windows. When I rebooted my computer, I get this error:
"Unknown Filesystem"
Grub Rescue >

I have seen other threads that involve making a livecd. As it turns out I have already installed the latest linux, so is there a way to get my PC to boot to either 12.04 Linux or Windows 7 without making a live CD

Answer (score 0):

Latest Ubuntu is 13.04. You could make livecd (on USB for example) and install new Ubuntu on older one (don't forget to format old Ubuntu partition). Then when booting - GRUB should see both Ubuntu and Windows. Always worked for me.

I understand that you are not able to boot neither Linux nor Windows?

Comment: I had formatted the partition where linux 10.10 was installed before using WUBI.

Comment: @Rhijul Boot from livecd and try [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).